# Dynamic html element in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Python Django.

I have a django collection objects, which is arranged in descending order of category_id as follows,

```
category_id         name
1               apple
1               orange
2               car
2               bus
2               truck
3               ifosys
3               wipro
```

How can I arrange each category items within `<ul></ul>` element.

Expected result,

```
<h4>From catgeory 1</h4>
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
</ul>
<h4>From catgeory 2</h4>
<ul>
    <li>car</li>
    <li>bus</li>
    <li>truck</li>
</ul>
<h4>From catgeory 3</h4>
<ul>
    <li>ifosys</li>
    <li>wipro</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused.  You can output variables in the template with {{variablename}}, or do for loops with arrays or dicts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: What collection object you have?

Answer (score 0):

Build your context dict with the category ID as key and value as `list`.

```
{
    '1': ["apple", "orange"],
    '2'" ["car", "bus"],
    ...
    ...
    '8': ["Foo", "Bar"],
}
```

And then iterate it at template. Template is just to render the data with some simple iterations and filters. You shouldn't burden the template with object build or parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, by collection of Django objects you mean a QuerySet. Then, as it was already mentioned, you need to group objects by category_id. The straightforward way would be to iterate over the Queryset and create a dictionary, in views.py:

```
grouped_objects = {}
for obj in obj_collection:
    if obj.category_id in grouped_objects.keys():
        grouped_objects[obj.category_id].append(obj)
    else:
        grouped_objects[obj.category_id] = [obj]
```

Now the grouped_objects dict is ready to be processed by template. I don't think that would be your entire context, so just pass it as a regular variable. Then you only need to use basic iteration tags:

```
{% for category, object_list in grouped_objects.items %}
    <h4>From category {{category}}</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <li>{{ obj.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Good luck!